# Android two way databinding is not working for edittext in Fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I am using one model for 2 fragments. First one is displaying countryName and countryCode, Second one is selecting country. When i select country i set a new value models field and going back to first fragment EditText is also setting empty text to models fields, thats why two way data binding is not working. If i change EditText to TextView, all is working fine.

Model:

```
public final ObservableField<String> countryName = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<String> countryCode = new ObservableField<>();

public void onCountrySelected(CountryEnum countryEnum) {
    countryName.set(countryEnum.getName());
    countryCode.set(countryEnum.getCode());
    getNavigator().onGoBack();
}
```

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/countryNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_56dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
        android:hint="@string/country_code"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.onCountryClick()}"
        android:text="@={viewModel.countryName}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/_48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@={viewModel.countryCode}"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="+998"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/countryNameTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryNameTextView"/>
```

Edit:
[image]

Country Enum:

```
public enum CountryEnum {

Country_1("Afghanistan", "Афганистан", "93", "--- --- ---"),
Country_2("Albania", "Албания", "355", "-- --- ----"),
Country_3("Algeria", "Алжир", "213", "--- -- -- --"),
Country_4("American Samoa", "Американское Самоа", "1684", "--- ----"),
Country_5("Andorra", "Андорра", "376", "-- -- --"),
Country_6("Angola", "Ангола", "244", "--- --- ---"),
Country_7("Anguilla", "Ангуилла", "1264", "--- ----"),
}
```

Comment: Where did you defined `onCountryClick()`?

Comment: when i click countryName EditText i will display second fragment

Comment: Can you post Country Enum with only few entries?

Comment: i have edited with Country Enums

Comment: Your country name should be a spinner why you have taken this as EditText?

Comment: I don't care whether it is Spinner or EditText, `Two way data binding` is not working for EditText, for TextView is working.

Answer (score 3):

For fragment, try to set lifecycleOwner

Simple example (Kotlin):

```
class FragmentMain : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewDataBinding: MainFragmentBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.main_fragment_profile,
        container,
        false
    )
    viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this

    return viewDataBinding.root
}
}
```